# Using Mongoose `pre` hook to get document before findOneAndUpdate()

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to use Mongoose `pre` and `post` hooks in my MongoDB backend in order to compare the document in its pre and post-saved states, in order to trigger some other events depending on what's changed. So far however I'm having trouble getting the document via the Mongoose `pre` hook.

According to the docs "pre hooks work for both doc.save() and doc.update(). In both cases this refers to the document itself... ". So I here's what I tried. First in my model/schema I have the following code:

```
let Schema = mongoose
  .Schema(CustomerSchema, {
    timestamps: true
  })
  .pre("findOneAndUpdate", function(next) {
    trigger.preSave(next);
  })
  // other hooks
}
```

... And then in my triggers file I have the following code:

```
exports.preSave = function(next) {
  console.log("this: ", this);
  }
};
```

But this is what logs to the console:

> this:  { preSave: [Function], postSave: [AsyncFunction] }

So clearly this didn't work. This didn't log out the document as I was hoping for. Why is `this` not the document itself here, as the docs themselves appear to indicate? And is there a way I can get a hold of the document with a `pre` hook? If not, is there another approach people have used to accomplish this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't retrieve the document in the `pre` hook.

According to the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#notes) `pre` is a query middleware and `this` refers to the query and not the document being updated.

Comment: Haris is correct, [the docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#types-of-middleware) list `findOneAndUpdate` as query middleware (`update` as well, for that matter). The fact is that these method simply don't have access to the document being updated.

Comment: Thanks, JohnnyHK and @Haris for the clarification. Those docs are tricky to make heads or tails of.

Comment: You can retrieve the document in /some/ `pre` hooks. It dependent on the type of middleware, not the pre/post. `findOneAndUpdate` is a query type middleware - but its not the `pre` specifically.

Comment: @scipilot what about document specific middleware such as remove(). I am not getting the context of this there as well. Please see my implementation below:

`Controller removes a object:

await entity.remove();

Pre hook:

entitySchema.pre('remove',async (next)=>{

    console.log("removing",this);     // ****** Output - removing {}

    await deleteAllUsersInEntity(this);
    await deleteAllThreadsInEntity(this);


})`

Comment: @HeetShah it's best if you open a new question with more context for people to help you there. But that should work: this should be the document. Is your document just empty? `{}` is an empty object, not nothing at all.

Answer (score 11):

The confusion arises due to the difference in the `this` context within each of the kinds of middleware functions. During **document** `pre` or `post` middleware, you can use `this` to access the document model, but not in the other hooks.

There are **three kinds** of middleware functions, all of which have pre and post stages.

In document middleware functions, `this` refers to the **document** (model).

- `init, validate, save, remove`

In query middleware functions, `this` refers to the **query**.

- `count,find,findOne,findOneAndRemove,findOneAndUpdate,update`

In aggregate middleware, `this` refers to the **aggregation** object.

- `aggregate`

It's explained here https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#types-of-middleware

Therefore you can simply access the document during  `pre("init"), pre("init"), pre("validate"), post("validate"), pre("save"), post("save"), pre("remove"), post("remove")`, but not in any of the others.

I've seen examples of people doing more queries within the other middleware hooks, to find the model again, but that sounds pretty dangerous to me.

The short answer seems to be, you need to change the original query to be document oriented, not query or aggregate style. It does seem like an odd limitation.

Answer (score 9):

As per documentation you pre hook cannot get the document in function, but it can get the query as follow

```
schema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', async function() { 
 const docToUpdate = await this.model.findOne(this.getQuery());
 console.log(docToUpdate); // The document that findOneAndUpdate() will modify
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to access document (or id) in ***query middleware functions***

```
UserSchema.pre<User>(/^(updateOne|save|findOneAndUpdate)/, async function (next) {
  const user: any = this

  if (!user.password) {
    const userID = user._conditions?._id
    const foundUser = await user.model.findById(userID)
    ...
  }
```

If someone needs the function to hash password when user password changes

```
UserSchema.pre<User>(/^(updateOne|save|findOneAndUpdate)/, async function (next) {
  const user: any = this

  if (user.password) {
    if (user.isModified('password')) {
      user.password = await getHashedPassword(user.password)
    }
    return next()
  }

  const { password } = user.getUpdate()?.$set
  if (password) {
    user._update.password = await getHashedPassword(password)
  }
  next()
})
```

user.password exists when "save" is the trigger

user.getUpdate() will return props that changes in "update" triggers